# MSBuild taskkill error

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm using MSBuild Visual Studio 2013 Express, and try to kill the vstest.console.exe process, if it is not initialized is giving error.

How do I stop the command and not have an error when the process is not initialized.

Code:

```
<exec  program="taskkill" commandline="/f /im vstest.console.exe" />
```

Error:

```
External Program Failed: taskkill (return code was 128)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IgnoreExitCode` parameter to ignore non-zero exit codes.

```
<exec  program="taskkill" commandline="/f /im vstest.console.exe"
       IgnoreExitCode="true"/>
```

Comment: Not working. Error: Unexpected attribute "IgnoreExitCode" on element <exec>

Comment: It is strange. You can use `ContinueOnError = "true"` instead.

Comment: Not working. Unexpected attribute "ContinueOnError" on element <exec>. I am use VS2013 Express.

Comment: MSBuild script is called using nant

Comment: Execute this programa C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe

Comment: Try build without nant directly by executing msbuild and see what will happen.